OpenCL device switching does not work in EmguCV
I'm currently working on a project that detects objects in an image using C# winforms. To do that, I'm using OpenCV with the EmguCV C# wrapper version 4.9.5494 from Nuget. I want to be able to switch which OpenCL device OpenCV is using to detect the objects, but this isn't working as expected.
Below is a simplified version of my code:
private void OpenCLTest()
{
    CvInvoke.UseOpenCL = true;

    List<Device> openCLDevices = new();

    VectorOfOclPlatformInfo platformInfoVector = OclInvoke.GetPlatformsInfo(); //Gets all available platforms.

    for (int i = 0; i < platformInfoVector.Size; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < platformInfoVector[i].DeviceNumber; j++) // Gets all the devices in a platform
        {
            Device openCLDevice = platformInfoVector[i].GetDevice(j);

            openCLDevices.Add(openCLDevice); // Adds a device to the device list.
        }
    }

    foreach (Device openCLDevice in openCLDevices)
    {
        CvInvoke.OclSetDefaultDevice(openCLDevice.Name); // Try to use each device in the device list and set it as the default device
        //Device.Default.Set(openCLDevice.NativeDevicePointer); Tried this as well, but with the same result.

        tryResize();

        Debug.WriteLine($"Resized image with {Device.Default.Name}");

        TryDetect();

        Debug.WriteLine($"Detected image with {Device.Default.Name}");
    }
}

private void tryResize()
{
    UMat uMat = new(@"Path\to\random\image.png", Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.Color); // UMat is supposed to use OpenCL where possible

    CvInvoke.Resize(uMat, uMat, new Size(1280, 704));

    uMat.Dispose();
}

private void TryDetect()
{
    Net net = DnnInvoke.ReadNetFromDarknet(@"Path\to\darknet\model.cfg", @"Path\to\darknet\model.weights");

    net.SetPreferableBackend(Emgu.CV.Dnn.Backend.OpenCV);
    net.SetPreferableTarget(Target.OpenCL); // Sets net target to use OpenCL.

    Mat mat = new(@"Path\to\random\image.png", Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.Color);

    CvInvoke.Resize(mat, mat, new(1280, 704));

    Mat blob = DnnInvoke.BlobFromImage(mat, 1/255F, swapRB: true);

    net.SetInput(blob);
    net.Forward(); // This is where the error occurs.

    blob.Dispose();
    mat.Dispose();
    net.Dispose();
}

I have 2 OpenCL capable devices in my laptop, a Nvidia RTX A1000 Ada Generation and an Intel Arc Graphics iGPU. Both are able to do the detection if I set my application to use either GPU as default in Windows graphics settings and not change anything to the default OpenCL device in my application. However, when I try to set the default OpenCL device for my application to something else than the Windows default (Setting iGPU in application but Windows tries to use dGPU for example) results in a !kernelQueue.empty() OpenCV Exception on the net.forward() method. If I first use the Windows default GPU to do a detection and then try to switch over to the other GPU, a CL_INVALID_DEVICE (-33) during call: clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE) error is thrown.
To try and troubleshoot this issue I tried to use OpenCL for a simpler task, resizing an image. This seems to work without issues on both devices, also after switching them in the application. Also printing the current default OpenCL device shows that the correct device is set. The only thing that does not work is the object detection. I also tried to use a different way to set the default device, without succes.
I'm not that experienced with using OpenCL and OpenCV and there seems to be very little documentation about the !kernelQueue.empty() exception, so I'm a bit lost.
Hopefully someone can provide some suggestions on what to try next. Thanks in advance!
